# Setting default selected value of selectlist inside an editor template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, drop-down-menu, selectlist, mvc-editor-templates

I have this code to set the default value of my select list:

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
    IList<Country> countryList = _countryRepository.GetAllCountry();

    var registerViewModel = new RegisterViewModel
    {
        CountryId = 52,
        CountryList = new SelectList(countryList, "CountryId", "CountryName", "Select Country")
    };

    return View(registerViewModel);
}
```

I have this on my view and this works well sets the selected country value to 52:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryId, Model.CountryList ,"Select Country") %>
```

However when I create an editor template for this, the default value for country is not selected

So, I change my current view to this:

```
 <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.CountryId,new { countries = Model.CountryList}) %>
```

Then I create my editor template like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.Int64?>" %>
<%= Html.DropDownList(
        String.Empty /* */, 
        (SelectList)ViewData["countries"], 
        "Select Country"
    )
%>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have solved this by replacing the code in my controller to :

```
CountryList = new SelectList(countryList, "CountryId", "CountryName",52 /*Default Country Id*/)
```

If you have better solutions, please let me know. I will change accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your Controller:

```
ViewData["CountryList"] = new SelectList(_countryRepository.GetAllCountry(), 52);
```

Then, on the View page, call the dropdown as follows:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Countries", ViewData["CountryList"] as SelectList)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Different ways to Archive this, This is One way**

---

**Step 1: Set the value you nee to be default selected. here I have passed  0 or 2**

```
    ViewBag.AssessmentfrezeId = IsUserHavefreeAssessment == false ? 2 : 0;
```

**Step 2:** Go to the Cshtml added the selected value like below.

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TestID, new SelectList(Model.Slots, "Id", "TimeSlot", @ViewBag.AssessmentfrezeId), "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control" })
```