# MVC.ViewBag is wrong?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, viewbag

I'm using

```
ViewBag.Something = session.Query<Something>().ToList();
```

To pass information from class Something to View and use it in selectList

> @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.model, new
>   SelectList(ViewBag.Something, "Id", "name"), "--Smthing--")

Is that bad? and how can i change it to be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The practice is not at all bad but it is recommonded to have a List property in our mode it self. in your case something like

```
public ActinResult YourActionMethod()
{
    YourModelObject.Something = session.Query<Something>().ToList();
    // And return your view after further code statements
    return View(YourModelObject);
}
```

Infact instead of the original list object you cancreate a `SelectList` object where you can easily bind key and value and send it to view. By this way you can add all your business and build your model at once place and can populate it from the location you want to. Later View will just use that model rather than applying some more intelligence to it. It helps alot as all your values resides under same object rather than some in Model and some in ViewBag.

Secondly this practice is also fine if you don't have this list at more than one place and you are not reusing this model in any views. Also if you want to access this property outside your view e.g. in Layout or in some parent view which is consuming your view.

You can take a look at following post which explains how to bind a list to your model.

**[Setting default selected value of selectlist inside an editor template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486577/setting-default-selected-value-of-selectlist-inside-an-editor-template)**

Comment: So if I use ViewBag in Create and Edit views its bad? and why is it bad?

Comment: As i said it a a feature provided by MVC so it is not bad actually. But usage of this feature could be bad if it increases maintainability. If there is only one place where you need to use this then you can opt for this otherwise if it is been used at saveral places then better to go with specific property. The good or bad of it depends on its usage and its need :) . Still recommended not to follow because while working on the view, you have to bind two different objects so it is an overhead. Still this is bearable if you have nested pages or those values are being used by parent page or child

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to add all my properties to the model of the view, but the ViewBag can be useful to add things that don't quite fit in the model. It can also be useful when binding to elements in the layout since it doesn't have access to the view's model.

Comment: how can I add propertys to model?